# Looking for a jQuery plugin for charts with dynamic multiple y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, flot

I'm looking for a jQuery chart plugin that has the ability to have multiple y-axis. I know such plugins exist, like Highcharts, but mine will need to be a little more involved.

The page is a data log that allow the users to select multiple sensors to show the log history for. These sensors can have various data types. For example, one sensor may be temperature in F, another may be temperature in C, another may be an on/off switch...

Once the sensors are selected, I do an AJAX call to get the data. So I won't know the number of sensors that are selected, or what type of data the values will be. I know the x-axis will be a date/time stamp... that's it.

Currently I have the page working with the user only being able to select one sensor at a time, and I'm using Flot. That is working great right now, but the users want the ability to show multiple sensors at the same time.

Does anyone have any experience with this that can point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Flot supports multiple axes: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-multiple/index.html - When you build a fiddle with your existing functionality we could have a look at how to expand it to multiple axes.

Comment: In the Highcharts you can manipulate axis by [addAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis) or [axis.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the requirements of your users who want to see multiple sensors at the same time in a chart. In that Case **[FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)** is the best option where you'll get an interactive line chart that can be configured for multiple axes.

Some of the features of the **Multi-Axis Line Chart** in FusionCharts include :

- Firstly, multiple axis on the same chart.
- Users are allowed to show or hide data sets plotted against that axis.
- You can draw the axis on left or tight side of the chart.
- The axis can be made visible or imaginary.
- One can plot multiple data-sets against same axis.
- Dynamic Sliding of axis from one end to the other.

You can also try out yourself in FusionCharts Editor. For any further assistance - @[Fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)? I know it has many features, including multi-axis capabilities ([example](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/multiaxis-line-charts/)).